# Table numbering starts at 2 when chngcntr / \counterwithout used

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, numbering, front-matter, chngcntr

I have used the `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` to remove the chapter number prefixing from table numbering yet my only table in the document is coming back as '2'

I have just done a little debug and it appears that the table of contents is getting included in the count of tables once `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` is declared in the preamble.

These are the packages and `chngcntr` commands in the preamble I am using.

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter} 
\counterwithout{table}{chapter} 
\lstset{numberbychapter=false}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Code}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}
\title{\ttitle}
```

I am also using `\frontmatter`. Could this be causing mischief with `chngcntr` when I employ the use of `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` ?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I have the same problem. My first table gets the number "Table 2" after using "\usepackage[margin=1cm, figurewithin=none, tablewithin=none, tableposition=top]{caption}"